# merge all of user2's work into user1's on git

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I used git to help develop a lil' web app project years ago (on a local dev machine, LAMP). I'm user1, but user2 wrote most, if not all of the actual code back then. I'm reviving the project and performing all the coding duties now. How do I merge all of user2's work (/home/users/user2/projectfoo.git) into user1's work (home/users/user1/projectfoo.git) bringing over all the files, folders, hooks, commit history and comments?

Comment: Do you wish to keep authorship of those respective users after the merge?

Comment: git merge origin/user2_branch does not work ?

Answer (score 1):

The following makes to add the git remote repo

`git remote add user2_repo user2@localhost:path/to/repository.git`

Take a pull from the repo to your local using

`git pull user2_repo branchname`

this makes you to pull all the changes and committed to the repository.